# I want div slide up & slide down action for jquery 1.3.2 version

Tags: jquery

I want slide up & slide down action which works with jquery 1.3.2 because in my project I can't use higher than that version..

I found one example in js fiddle. But it is for jquery 1.4.2. Not working for 1.3.2.

**JS**

```
$("#clickk").hover(function () {
  $("#monster").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Here is the [fiddle  link](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JcBAd/)

Comment: Why can't you use a newer version of jQuery?

Comment: Because My whole project done with 1.3.2 only.. by that time standards.. Only because of this action I can't change the version...

Comment: You can use multiple copies (different versions) of jQuery on one site using .noConflict() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @zjd That is one option,But thing is why it's not working in 1.3.2  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJLrp/) (using jQuery 1.3.2) :

**Updated JS:**

```
function toggle() {
  $("#monster").slideToggle("fast");
}

$("#clickk").hover(toggle,toggle);
```

---

The difference was in hover function in both the versions :

From 1.3.2

```
hover:function(E,F){return this.mouseenter(E).mouseleave(F)}
```

From 1.4.2

```
hover:function(a,b){return this.mouseenter(a).mouseleave(b||a)}
```

Notice that in 1.4.2 the hover sets **mouseleave** to same as **mouseenter** when not specified.